# How to add multiple HTML pages in Ionic For Hybrid Mobile Application?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have two pages in HTML as sign in and sign up page but unable to make them in single index.html page.

My project is Hybrid mobile app development.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to use ionic navigation directives. See the link below to read more on it. Inside the ionic directive lies Angular's Routers.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/

Answer (score 1):

in ionc2 you can use NavController

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/

for more demonstration check this link: 
https://www.joshmorony.com/a-simple-guide-to-navigation-in-ionic-2/

> to generate a new page you can write "ionic g page pageName" using CLI